# Error while using External Evaluator (Python)

Tags: python, external-calls, external-language-cell

[image]

In the above screenshot, I've shared the installed and registered version of python. However, when I try to use it, it ends up with an error.

```
res = ExternalEvaluate[session, "import math
  [math.sqrt(i) for i in range(10)]"]
```

[image]

I tried another methods, there also I faced errors

```
res = ExternalEvaluate[session, "/home/FDM.py"]
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: The first command `math.sqrt` gives an error (`unexpected indent`) because there are 2 spaces before `[math. ...` (maybe it was added after pasting). For running a file, following this [workflow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ExecuteAPythonFileWithExternalEvaluate.html), `File` is used.

Comment: Was Enter/Return key pressed after `import math`? Also does something simple like `1 + 1` return a result? Which version of Mma and which OS?

Comment: I would not expect the second attempt to be successful as it is not valid Python syntax. Maybe it would work at the Python terminal but the session is at the language parser.

Comment: For the third check all your spacing. The Python editor used to make and run the file might be fixing leading/trailing spaces for you before sending to the parser. That is not happening for the external session.

Comment: Here is the correct syntax: `res = ExternalEvaluate["Python", 
  "import math\n[math.sqrt(i) for i in range(10)]"]`

Comment: @Edmund Mathematica version 12.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. And yes, for simple calculation like 1+1, it returns a result